# Need htaccess code to rewrite URLs with trailing slash except XML files

Tags: xml, wordpress, .htaccess, sitemap

Have the following code in .htaccess which rewrites URLs in WordPress from have no trailing slash to having one. For example, www.domain.com/post -> www.domain.com/post/.

Problem is, it's doing it for sitemap.xml which breaks it. How can I exclude .xml files?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just insert another [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) excluding URLs ending in `.xml`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.xml$
```

Comment: When I add that, the XML file is excluded but the page is blank. It has source code but doesn't display anything. [Here's the link to the sitemap file](http://www.cetancorp.com/sitemap_index.xml). It's generated by the Yoast SEO WordPress plugin. [Here's how it should look](https://yoast.com/sitemap_index.xml).

Comment: I don't see the problem with your sitemap. When I load these URLs, none is empty and both seem properly formatted.

Comment: When I open it in Chrome/Firefox the page is blank. The source looks right, but the page being blank concerns me.

Comment: Figured it out. There was an error in the Chrome console: Unsafe attempt to load URL http://domain.com/main-sitemap.xsl/

I added an exclusion for .xsl and all is well. Thanks!